The issue of %5c causing output exceptions in C language
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y = 0, w = 0;
    scanf("%d %5c", &y, &w);
    printf("%d,%c\n", y, w);
    return 0;
}

When i input 2000 12345, the output is 1845,1.
When i input 1000 12345, the output is 821,1.
and when i input 2000 23456, the output is 1846, 2.
But if i change %5c to %4c, input 2000 12345 corresponding to output 2000,1.
Why? Where do these 1845, 1846, 821 come from?
I think the problem arises in %5c.

%5c reads 5 bytes into a 4-byte integer.

When there is a mismatch between the format string and the variable type, there are no rules as to what happens.

@kangaroo, Save time, enable all compiler warnings,.

It is supposed to be an array of 5 chars. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Note what C11 §7.21.6.2 The fscanf function ¶12 says of the %c format: Matches a sequence of characters of exactly the number specified by the field width (1 if no field width is present in the directive). If no l length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of a character array large enough to accept the sequence. No null character is added. (Bold emphasis added). You are trying to store 5 characters in a 4-byte integer.  You're only printing one of those characters.'


I think the problem arises

The problem arises from that the code is invalid and breaks the rules of the language.
An argument for %5c should be a char * pointer that points to a memory of at least 5 chars. The &w is a pointer to an int, so the code is invalid.
Research the term "undefined behavior" in C programming langauge.

Why? Where do these 1845,1846,821 come from?

Facts / lucky guesses:

you are on x86_64 architecture
int has 32-bits, 4 bytes
stack grows downward
y is in a higher address than w
little endian
1 in ascii is 49, 2 is 50, 3 = 51, 4 = 52, 5 = 53, 6 = 54
%c takes an int argument and prints the 8 lowest significant bits of the argument as a character to the output, ignoring other bits

What happens:

the first input is assigned to &y
the first 4 bytes of the second input is assigned to &w
the next bytes of are assigned to &y

because &y has higher address than &w, because stack grows downwards
bytes are assigned starting from least significant bytes, overwriting the first input assignment.



So for example:



input
printf("%x %x", y, w)
w =
y =




2000 12345
735 34333231
'4'<<24|'3'<<16|'2'<<8|'1'
(2000 & ~0xff) | '5'


1000 12345
335 34333231
'4'<<24|'3'<<16|'2'<<8|'1'
(1000 & ~0xff) | '5'


2000 12346
736 34333231
'4'<<24|'3'<<16|'2'<<8|'1'
(2000 & ~0xff) | '6'




if i change %5c to %4c, input 2000 12345 corresponding to output 2000,1.

Then the last byte of input 5 is ignored and doesn't get assigned to y. w stays.

"should be a char *" --> more like char *, signed char *, unsigned char *, or void *.

The issue with your code lies in the scanf function. The format specifier %5c is used to read exactly 5 characters, but you're trying to store them in a single int variable w. This will lead to undefined behavior.
Here's a corrected version of your code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y = 0;
    char w[6]; // Array to store 5 characters + null terminator
    scanf("%d %5s", &y, w); // Use %5s to read up to 5 characters into a string
    printf("%d,%s\n", y, w); // Use %s to print the string
    return 0;
}

In this version, w is declared as a character array to store up to 5 characters plus a null terminator. The format specifier %5s is used to read up to 5 characters into the string w, and %s is used to print the string.
If you really need int s.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y = 0, w=0;
    scanf("%d %d", &y, &w); 
    printf("%d,%d\n", y, w); 
    return 0;
}


I recommend to always use option -Wall: gcc -Wall a.c. It tells:
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5:17: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d %5c", &y, &w);
               ~~^       ~~
               %5lc


The suggestion (use %5lc) is misleading :)

@chqrlie I think the compiler will tell us 2 choices: either use %5lc to match the int pointer. Or change the pointer &w.

It is misleading because w does not have the type wchar_t that %lc expects (type wchar_t happens to be typedef'd to int of the target platform), furthermore it is quite obscure what %5lc means on any platform, and likely to cause undefined behavior in the current case.  %5d would be fine, albeit probably not what the OP expects, but it is unclear what kangaroo expects anyway.


Why? Where do these 1845,1846,821 come from?

%5c in scanf reads exactly 5 characters from the input and stores them as characters in a char array without adding a null terminator. But the code you provided currently is sing %5c with an int variable (int w) may causes scanf to interpret the w variable’s memory incorrectly. So it causes unpredictable results.
If you want to use %5c properly, you can declare w as a char array of sufficient size instead of int variable.
int y = 0;
char w[6] = {0};

scanf("%d %5c", &y, w);
printf("%d, %s\n", y, w);

